# Possible to make an XML template for Android display different numbers of buttons?

Tags: java, android, xml, templates

I understand that XML templates in Android generally have static elements and that's pretty much the point of them to layout the page, but I am designing an app that has the same elements on every page, except for a varying number of buttons at the bottom depending on what data is being displayed.

Now, I could (and have so far) simply make 5 different XML templates each with one additional button element added so I can display 1 to 5 buttons and call the appropriate template depending on what is required, but that seems terribly inelegant to me.  It works though.  I just feel like I must be missing something since I am new to this platform and XML templating in general.

To be specific, given the above background:  Is there any way I could use a single template and have it use a varying number of buttons at the end?  I have been cautioned against implementing layouts both programmatically in java and in XML, but might this be an exception to that rule?  And if so how would I go about it?

Please let me know if any more information is needed to answer this question.  As it is a fairly general question, I didn't include any code, but will provide it if necessary. 
 Thank you!

Comment: You may have been cautioned against implementing layouts both programmatically in java and in XML, but classes such as [`ViewStub`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) show

Comment: You may have been cautioned against implementing layouts both programmatically in java and in XML, but classes such as [`ViewStub`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) do allow for greater flexibility in layout design while avoiding some of the downsides of programmatic layout creation. And if you create your own View classes or widgets, you're going to have to do some layout-related things programmatically anyway (you could even create your own XML attributes, the parsing of which would need to be handled in the constructor[s] for your custom view[s]/widget[s]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put as many buttons as you want at the bottom.  Then in each activity, you access each button and then call:

```
buttonX.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

for the ones you don't need in that view.

Comment: Fantastic, a simple and elegant solution!